# Install4J: stderr and return code redirection into variable gets written only once

Tags: java, install4j

I'm using Install4j 6.1.6, and I'm trying to do the following:

I want to run a jar file externally with the parameters coming from the installer (first screen) then show the result on a second screen.

---

So, the first screen has:

1. some input fields
2. a "Run executable or batch file" action

   - executable: ${installer:sys.javaHome}\bin\java
   - arguments from the previous input fields put together
   - "Wait for termination" is checked
   - "Variable name for return code" is **my-returncode**
   - "Redirect stderr" to installer variable **my-stderr**
3. and a "Run script" action which goes to the next screen automatically

   - context.gotoScreen(context.getScreenById("nextScreenId"));
     return true;

The second screen shows the appropriate labels based on the values of **my-returncode** and **my-stderr**.

**Every case is working perfectly fine.**

However, I decided to change the "Back button" on the second screen *to be always visible* because this way the user can fix the problem (if he entered something wrong in the input fields).

So I checked "Can be executed multiple times" on the "Run executable or batch file" action on the first screen.

---

Now when I type in erroneous data into the input fields, click `Next >` the script will run and fail, the second screen will say that there was a mistake. **my-returncode** and **my-stderr** contain the exit code and the error message.

Then I click the `< Back` button and fix the problems, I click `Next >` then the script runs successfully this time but I still get the previous errors because **my-returncode** and **my-stderr** weren't updated, they still contain the last error message and exit code!

How could I solve this problem and make Install4J update the variables in this case?

---

**Update:**

I have realized that the second action (to go to the next screen) is entirely unnecessary, so I deleted it.

This still hasn't solved my problem, here are the relevant parts from `.install4j/installation.txt`:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1199]: Show screen
       Variable changed: shouldLaunchExternalScript=true[class java.lang.String]
       Variable changed: externalScriptDataFolder=F:\badfolderpath[class java.lang.String]
```

This is the screen where the user can select to launch this external script and set the data folder. I clicked the "launch script" radio button and set a bad folder path.

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction [ID 1367]: Execute action
       Property arguments: [-cp, ./*, -Ddata.dir=F:\badfolderpath, ...]
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property returnCodeVariable: my-returncode
       Property stdoutRedirectionMode: No redirection
       Property stdoutVariableName: 
       Property workingDirectory: ...
       Property failOnStderrFileError: false
       Property failOnStdinFileError: false
       Property failOnStdoutFileError: false
       Property rollbackExecutable: null
       Property rollbackArguments: null
       Property rollbackWorkingDirectory: null
       Property stderrRedirectionMode: To installer variable
       Property stderrVariableName: my-stderr
       Property stdinRedirectionMode: No redirection
       Property environmentVariables: {}
       Property keepConsoleWindow: true
       Property showWindowsConsole: false
       Property useRollbackExecutable: false
       Property includeParentEnvironmentVariables: true
       Property stdinString: 
       Property timeout: 0
       Property stdinFile: null
       Property stderrFile: null
       Property stdoutFile: null
       Property wait: true
       Property waitForStreams: true
       Property executable: c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\e4jb23d.tmp_dir1564671223\jre\bin\java
       Property logArguments: true
       used working dir: ...
       execute using batch file
```

The script is launched with the given parameters and it will fail:

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction [ID 1367]: return value is 1
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction [ID 1367]: Variable changed: my-stderr
       Variable changed: my-returncode=1[class java.lang.Integer]
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction [ID 1367]: return value is 1
        Execute action not successful after 19696 ms
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1199]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1360]: Show screen
```

Return code 1 means fail, 0 means success in the external script. The variables got updated, and now I see on the second screen that the external script failed. I click back now and fix the problem (select a correct folder path):

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1360]: command: go back 1 screens using history
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1199]: Show screen
       Variable changed: shouldLaunchExternalScript=true[class java.lang.String]
       Variable changed: externalScriptDataFolder=F:\goodfolderpath[class java.lang.String]
```

The variables got updated and the external script is launched again with the correct arguments:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.RunExecutableAction: Execute action
       Property arguments: [-cp, ./*, -Ddata.dir=F:\goodfolderpath, ...]
       Property rollbackSupported: false
       Property includeParentEnvironmentVariables: true
       Property stderrFile: null
       Property executable: c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\e4jb23d.tmp_dir1564671223\jre\bin\java
       Property stdinString: 
       Property wait: true
       Property stdinFile: null
       Property stdoutFile: null
       Property waitForStreams: true
       Property logArguments: true
       Property timeout: 0
       Property stderrVariableName: my-stderr
       Property stdinRedirectionMode: No redirection
       Property rollbackArguments: null
       Property stdoutRedirectionMode: No redirection
       Property rollbackWorkingDirectory: null
       Property workingDirectory: ...
       Property stdoutVariableName: 
       Property environmentVariables: {}
       Property returnCodeVariable: my-returncode
       Property rollbackExecutable: null
       Property stderrRedirectionMode: To installer variable
       Property useRollbackExecutable: false
       Property failOnStdinFileError: false
       Property failOnStdoutFileError: false
       Property failOnStderrFileError: false
       Property showWindowsConsole: false
       Property keepConsoleWindow: true
       used working dir: ...
       execute using batch file
       Variable changed: my-stderr
       Variable changed: my-returncode=0[class java.lang.Integer]
       Execute action successful after 16416 ms
```

The script ran successfully, and the variables were changed (my-returncode was 1, now it's 0).

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1199]: command: move 1 screens, executing actions, checking condition
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.FormScreen [ID 1360]: Show screen
```

However, on the result screen, I still see the non-updated, previous my-stderr, and my-returncode values indicating there was an error running the external script.

Comment: All variables should be set again if the action actually runs again. Please check the .install4j/installation.log file to see what the two executions of the same action are actually doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @IngoKegel, I have updated the original post with the installation log, could you take a look at it, please?

Comment: OK, so the variables are updates correctly, it's only the display that is not updated. How are you displaying the variable values? Generally, live binding of variable values in most situations is available since install4j 8.

Comment: I have three multiline labels: success, fail, error message. They all have this visibility script: `return (Integer)context.getVariable("my-returncode") == 0;` (!= instead of == for fail and error message) and the error message label's value is simply `${installer:my-stderr}`
When I run the installer for the first time both cases work fine (it shows the failure message when the script fails, success when it succeeds). The problem is when I go back a screen and rerun it the second screen doesn't get updated for the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue by adding this line to the second screen's preactivation script:

```
formEnvironment.reinitializeFormComponents();
```